# Strange behavour with fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

I am beginner in processes and fork(). Could you please explain why does this program end only when i press Enter in the terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  char *arg[] = {"/usr/bin/ls", "-l", "-a", "--color=auto", 0 };

    if(fork() == 0) {
        printf("In child process: \n");
        execv(arg[0] ,arg);
        printf("I will never be called :((( \n");
    }

    printf("Execution continues in parent process\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the process end when you hit return, or is it merely that you don't see the prompt that was printed before the output of `ls` and you are hitting return to get another prompt?

Comment: Try adding a `wait` in the parent to delay the printing of that initial prompt.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, the process ends only when i press Enter

Comment: Why do you think that?  I suspect the output of `ls` caused the "Execution continues..." message to scroll off the top of your screen, and the process is in fact complete.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Because after the execution of program i see the output of ls program but don't get a new prompt until Enter is pressed. That is why i thought that the process ends after the keypress

Comment: Do you understand now why your interpretation is incorrect?  The program is done, but the prompt that the shell printed has scrolled off the top of your screen.  Hitting return just causes the shell to emit another prompt.  Experiment by adding a `sleep` before the `exec`, or a `wait` in the parent.